# How to fix relative module error for a newly created nuxt.js app with starter template?

Tags: vuejs2, installation, vue-cli, nuxt.js

I tried to create a nuxt app with the guide from the official website, chose default options because I wanted the starter template but on running `npm run dev`, I keep encountering the error:

```
This relative module was not found:
 * ./components/nuxt-error.vue in ./.nuxt/index.js
```

I've tried searching about it but I couldn't find any useful resource/fix. I've also tried `vue init nuxt-community/starter-template` for the installation but I still get the same error.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution. I couldn’t figure out the error because the nuxt-error.vue file was actually imported correctly. Turns out “npm” installations have been giving me issues (had issues with TailwindCSS too).

So if you ever encounter this error on loading the base nuxt app, recreate the project using “yarn” instead. Works like magic!

Comment: It sure did for me.